# Grails unable to resolve class org.grails.compiler.injection.TraitInjectionSupport

Tags: java, grails, grails-3.0

I have started learning Grails. For project specific purpose, I have installed Grails 3.0.0 in Ubuntu. Whenever I started a grails project in IDE(IntelliJ). I got the following error

```
| Error Failed to compile idea-list-injected-traits.groovy: startup failed:
idea-list-injected-traits.groovy: 2: unable to resolve class org.grails.compiler.injection.TraitInjectionSupport
 @ line 2, column 1.
   import org.grails.compiler.injection.TraitInjectionSupport
   ^

1 error
 (Use --stack trace to see the full trace)
| Error occurred running Grails CLI: null (Use --stack trace to see the full trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I solve it? I am totally new in Grails. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting

```
~/.grails/repository
```